# date string has non visible characters. How do we get rid of them?

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, sql-server

I've got a web application that uses a javascript calendar.  When the user clicks on a date it populates the date label (e.g. 1/10/2018).  When I hit my run button, the inputted information including this date goes to a SProc in SQL Server.  For some reason I've got extra characters that you can't see.  For instance:

```
 Exec Get_Date '2','6/1/2018', 1, 100, 101, 500, 50
```

Imediately throws an error. If I retype the date like this:

```
'6/1/2018'
```

it works fine.  Obviously visually there isn't anything different between the two dates.  I did a little investigating using SQL to look at character values using this script:

```
DECLARE @nstring NVARCHAR(100)
SET @nstring ='‎6‎/‎1‎/‎2018'

DECLARE @position INT
 SET @position = 1

DECLARE @CharList TABLE (
 Position INT,
 UnicodeChar NVARCHAR(1),
 UnicodeValue INT
 )

WHILE @position <= DATALENGTH(@nstring)
 BEGIN
 INSERT @CharList
 SELECT @position as Position
 ,CONVERT(nchar(1),SUBSTRING(@nstring, @position, 1)) as UnicodeChar
 ,UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@nstring, @position, 1)) as UnicodeValue
 SET @position = @position + 1
 END

SELECT * FROM @CharList
```

Once I run this script I get the attached output.  As you can see, I have ? being added (e.g. ?6/?1/?2018) and I have a bunch of trailing spaces that don't even have Unicode equivallents(I tried the rtrim function and that didn't do anything). If I do this:

```
Select Len('6/1/2018') or Select(rtrim('6/1/2018))
```

I would expect that a value of 8 should come back, or at the very least , a value of 11 which would account for the question marks in front of the numbers; however, I get a value of 13.  I tried converting the string in C sharp before I pass it to the query string, but it also immediately fails. How do I clean this seemingly correct date of type string (string strDate), in either javascript or c sharp? 
[SQL Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1nUx.png)

Comment: Try preventing form submit using script and checking string length in browser. Then check length received on submit. Finding source of issue seems like best approach

Comment: It looks like it is coming from my javascript calendar.  Using a simple alert(strDate.length) I get the value of 13 as soon as I click on a new date. I'm using glDatePicker which is pretty straight forward.

Comment: The problem is the line feed character \n...Thanks @charlietfl !!! Sometimes when you chase a rabbit down a rabbit hole, you get tunnel vision and forget to do the obvious.

Comment: Not sure how a date ends up with line feed but glad it worked out. Sounded like a very strange scenario that could easily be resolved though

Comment: "When I hit my run button, the inputted information including this date goes to a SProc in SQL Server."

Well there's your problem. Your web-server should ideally deal with this at some point between receiving the http request and talking to the database. The tools available for processing this in C# or *just about any language* are going to be *far* more appropriate than the tools available in TSQL.

Comment: I'm not sure why there is a requirement to store the date as a string.  That's generally a really bad idea that causes problems...just like this.